# How to stop a currently running dataflow in Analytics Studio datamanager?

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein

According to the documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_integrate_dataflow_run.htm), starting a dataflow in the datamanager should result in

- a greyed-out `Start`-action (see 3. in documentation linked above)
- the appearance of an `x` to stop the currently running dataflow (see 5. in documentation linked above)

However I'm unable to observe these changes and thus also unable to stop my currently running dataflow.

When I attempt to start a currently running dataflow again, I do get the notification (as a warning popup) that I cannot start the dataflow because it is already running.

So, my question - as the title suggests, how can I stop a dataflow that is currently running? Preferably in the UI, but I'd also consider some API-Call or an equivalent to the apex-job overview.

As I observed quite some webbrowser-related issues in Analytics Studio in general, I tried "finding the `x`" in Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, this is related to the language you've set for your user. Opening the view with a German user, you can see this: (note the missing `x`)
[image: German Data Manager]

The same view in English looks like this:[image: English Data Manager]

So for the time being, change your language to English and click the button. You *could* also edit the text `Wird ausgeführt` to make it shorter:[image: Edited Data Manager]